# /proc/pid/maps start address is different in Ubuntu 16 and Ubuntu 18

Tags: memory, maps

In Ubuntu 18 (64 bit), the running processes start/load address seemed to be randomized each time the same application is run - it no longer starts at  0x400000. May I know if this is caused the ASLR enabled? In Ubuntu 18, I need to set the ASLR to 0 in order the for start address to be fixed each time the same application is executed, but in Ubuntu 16 and below, this is not necessary. 
What has changed in Ubuntu 18?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, side-channel attacks due to CPU architecture issues were all over the news recently. In order to mitigate these types of attacks, the [Kernel Page Table Isolation](https://lwn.net/Articles/741878/) (previously called KAISER) patch set was developed and [merged](https://lwn.net/Articles/742404/) into the linux kernel 4.15RC6.

Ubuntu 18.04 used [kernel 4.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_(Bionic_Beaver)) on initial release, which explains why ASLR is enabled by default in Ubuntu 18.04 and later.

Comment: hi Samveen, thanks for the answer! I was trying to find out what technology or improvement was done so that I can read up about it. The side-channel attacks you mentioned, are they the Spectre and Meltdown attacks?

Comment: @alvin yes. These are in direct response to Spectre and Meltdown.